# Row lookup in awk for a column between two files

Tags: arrays, awk, lookup, delimiter

I have FILE1 as follows:

```
  CX    998900  998900  -   CX:998900:998900:**ENSG00000000001:E4**:AAAT:4.468:A1
  CX    998903  998903  -   CX:998903:998903:**ENSG00000000001:E4**:CAAT:6.600:A1
  CX    998889  998890  -   CX:998889:998890:**ENSG00000000003:E5**:TAAT:7.523:A1
  CX    998891  998891  -   CX:998891:998891:**ENSG00000000003:E5**:TAAT:7.518:A1
  CX    998881  998881  -   CX:998881:998881:**ENSG00000000002:E6**:AAAT:4.468:A1
  CX    998883  998883  -   CX:998883:998883:**ENSG00000000003:E6**:AAAT:5.784:A1
  CX    998880  998880  -   CX:998880:998880:**ENSG00000000003:E6**:AAAT:5.784:A1
  CX    998884  998884  -   CX:998884:998884:**ENSG00000000003:E6**:TAAT:6.202:A1
```

I have FILE2 as the list of ids highlighted in bold:

```
 ENSG00000000001:E4
 ENSG00000000003:E5
 ENSG00000000002:E6  
 ENSG00000000003:E6
 ENSG00000000002:E5
```

I am trying to use the following awk command to get the binary count of the ids from FILE2 in FILE1

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} FNR==1 && f{print f;for(k in a) print a[k], a[k] in b; delete b}{b[$5]; f=FILENAME}END{print f; for(k in a) print a[k], a[k] in b; delete b}' FILE2 FILE1
```

Such that I get

```
ENSG00000000001:E4  1
ENSG00000000003:E5  1
ENSG00000000002:E6  1  
ENSG00000000003:E6  1
ENSG00000000002:E5  0
```

Comment: what is binary count? 1 if there are any, 0 if not?

Comment: also, note that the `**` in FILE1 are misleading. I guess you want them to be bold, but within a code block they look like the original, raw data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your counts are off or there is some unspecified condition

```
$ awk -F'**' -v OFS=':' 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++; next} 
                         $1 in c{print $1,c[$1]; next} 
                                {print $1,0} ' file1 file2

ENSG00000000001:E4:2
ENSG00000000003:E5:2
ENSG00000000002:E6:1
ENSG00000000003:E6:3
ENSG00000000002:E5:0
```

Oh, I see not the count but an indicator, for that replace `c[$2]++` with `c[$2]=1`

If `**` is not part of the file, you have to change it slightly

```
$ awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{c[$4 FS $5]=1; next} 
             $0 in c{print $0,c[$0]; next} 
                    {print $0,0} ' file1 file2

ENSG00000000001:E4 1
ENSG00000000003:E5 1
ENSG00000000002:E6 1
ENSG00000000003:E6 1
ENSG00000000002:E5 0
```

this can be further simplified, as @fedorqui commented.

```
$ awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{c[$4 FS $5];next} {print $0, $0 in c}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Awesome it's working! Thanks a lot. Sorry I tried to out ids in bold and came off as asterisk instead.

Comment: Nice. You can even say `print $0, $0 in  c ? c[$0] : 0`

Answer (score 0):

Let's use some non-intelligent approach. That is, grepping every single line in file1 against the whole file2 and get the return code of `grep`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\t%d\n" "$line" "$(grep -q "$line" f1 && echo 1 || echo 0)"
done < f2
```

Comment: I had tried grepping but it takes a long time since the files is huge.